# How can I make the hands stopping at the ground level?

Tags: animation

I'm animating a person who kneels and puts his hands on the ground but I don't know how to make the hands stopping at the ground level (the hands, since they are parented to the chest, follow its movement)
Could somebody help me?
Hope I've made myself clear!

Comment: there's floor constraint did you try it ?

Comment: Just tried and it works! Thank you, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @Chebhou may you answer this? we're up to 89%!